# Does de-structuring require(d) modules have any performance benefit in node?

Tags: node.js, commonjs

Is `const lodash = require('lodash');` any performant than `const {get} = require('lodash');`

I am looking to find out if later is faster and/or more memory efficient? This is strictly in node realm ( NOT talking about front end where bundle size comes into picture)

Comment: Just saves a bit of typing in some circumstances.  `require()` should be running at server initialization time anyway so I'm surprised that a tiny different in performance (if it's even noticeable) would even matter.  As with any performance issues, if it really matters to you, then measure it yourself for your specific circumstance.  Both produce a loaded module and one variable in the local scope so I'd be surprised if there's any memory consumption difference.